# Repeatedly install SSMS 2008 when building projects in VS2010

Tags: linq, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

Since after reinstall Win 7, VS2010, SQL Server 2008 on my PC, every time when build/debug a project which uses LINQ feature, the VS2010 will prompt up a message box showing installing SSMS 2008. It will finish install process in about 30sec. But this happens every time. Has anyone get this issue too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the final answer in this thread:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/6270c7c4-d58b-4b3b-99ca-f7c934bffa13/

Summary:

It could be that your SQL Server install media needs to be in the drive to install an additional component.